# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/facebook/imagepipeline/backends/okhttp/BuildConfig.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I already gone through all question, not figure out what will work for me. Tried number of suggestions but not working yet. Please help.

**This is the Build Gradle in module 'imagepipelineokhttp'**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/imagepipeline-okhttp-v0.4.0.jar')
}
```

**Build.gradle from App**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypacakge.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'

    compile files('libs/AF-Android-SDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-2.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/parcelgen.jar')
    compile files('libs/scribe-1.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')

    compile project(':cropper')
    compile project(':drawee')
    compile project(':fastImageProcessing')
    compile project(':fbcore')
    compile project(':fresco')
    compile project(':imagepipeline')
    compile project(':imagepipelineokhttp')
    compile project(':lib')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':swipelistview')

}
```

**The Error**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/facebook/imagepipeline/backends/okhttp/BuildConfig.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Please share the full trace of the error to help us understand better the issue.

Comment: @arodriguezdonaire ok, I am updating the question

Comment: @arodriguezdonaire any luck?

Comment: I would say that 'imagepipeline' is compiling 'imagepipelineokhttp' so you should put this in reverse order.